# Write file names in to a file using UNIX command

Tags: shell, unix

I'm working on a similar scenario where is have to insert a list of filenames into a filename.txt from a particular directory. This need to be accomplished in one single command since i want to use this command in a Autosys Job. I have tried the below scenario but its inserting the filenames along with the directory but i'm expecting the output filenames without the directory. Please suggest me how to proceed with this.

List of filenames:
    `ls /path/file*.csv
    file1.csv
    file2.csv 
    file3.csv 
    file4.csv 
    file5.csv`

Command that i'm using:
    `/path/file*.csv > /path/file.txt`

Current Output:
    `cat /path/file.txt 
    /path/file1.csv 
    /path/file2.csv 
    /path/file3.csv 
    /path/file4.csv 
    /path/file5.csv`

**Expected Output:** 
    `cat /path/file.txt 
    file1.csv 
    file2.csv 
    file3.csv 
    file4.csv 
    file5.csv`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cd /path`, then `ls -1 *.csv > /other/path/file.txt`

Comment: Just to add to the previous comment, to issue in a one-liner put a semi-colon ( ; ) between the cd command and the ls one.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks a lot guys!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate take:

```
find /path -name 'file*.csv' -printf '%f\n' > /path/files.txt
```

Although that will descend into subdirectories, if there are any.

---

Without descending into subdirectories:

```
find /path -maxdepth 1 -name 'file*.csv' -printf '%f\n' > /path/files.txt
#          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```